# Reading in character strings from text file in C

Tags: c, string, file, struct, strtok

I need to write a program that reads in strings from a text file and stores each word in a struct, i.e. if the first line in the text file is:

TOYOTA COROLLA 2014 WHITE

Toyota would go into structname.model, corolla would go into structname.make, etc. 
I am having trouble with reading each string into their according element in the struct. My source code (which I have not posted here bc it is very long and a large percentage of it is pretty irrelevant to this problem) compiles with no errors, but I am 99% sure it is a problem with my loop which is supposed to be reading in the values:

```
carRecord cars[10]; //declares array of structs containing carRecord info
char filename[256];
char buf[256];
FILE *carfile;

printf("Please enter the name of a file to read car records from (followed by the file extension): ");
scanf("%s", filename);

carfile = fopen(filename, "r");

if (!carfile)
{
    printf("File failed to open.\n");
}

printf("ERROR CHECK 1");

int i = 0;
while ((fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), carfile) != NULL) && i < 10)
{
    cars[i].make = strdup(strtok(buf, " "));

    cars[i].model = strdup(strtok(buf, " "));

    cars[i].year = atoi(strdup(strtok(buf, " ")));

    cars[i].color = strdup(strtok(buf, " "));

    i++;
}
```

The first error check prints, and then the program crashes. I have a *strong, scary feeling* this has to do with the malloc command, but I am pretty new to C and have absolutely no idea how to implement it.

If at all helpful, the struct declaration for carRecord is:

```
struct carRecord{
    char* make;     //make of car
    char* model;    //model of car
    int year;           //year of car
    char* color;    //color of car
};
```

(EDIT: code has been updated to reflect below comments)

Comment: Is this C or Objective C?

Comment: So many problems. You're never allocating any space for `filename` or `buf`. You should declare them as arrays, not pointers. When you do `cars[i].make = buf`, it simply copies the pointer, so all the cars will point to the **same** buffer. And you're copying that same pointer to `model` and `color` -- you should use `strtok()` to split the line up at spaces.

Comment: Then you need to use `strdup()` to make a copy of the string, and put that pointer into `carRecord`.

Comment: Sorry, this is C, not objective C.

Comment: And this makes sense, thank you. But with strtok() how do I assign each split up token to a different element of the struct? I am not sure how to do this staying inside the while loop.

Comment: `cars[i].make = strdup(strtok(buf, " ")); cars[i].model = strdup(strtok(buf, NULL)); cars[i].year = atoi(strtok(buf, NULL)); cars[i].color = strdup(strtok(buf, NULL));`

Comment: @Barmar No, it should be `strtok(NULL, " ")` for 2nd or later.

Comment: You say "I have a strong, scary feeling this has to do with the malloc command..." but there's no `malloc` in your code.

Comment: @shoover I think he means that solving it will require using `malloc`.

Comment: @MikeCAT it just goes to show that even the masters can have an off comment every now and then.... `:)` Happens to the best of us...

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, if you allocate memory to the structure elements, you'll get desired result. Else, as you mentioned, use calloc/malloc.

```
struct carRecord{
    char make[100];     //make of car
    char model[100];    //model of car
    int year;           //year of car
    char color[100];    //color of car
};
```